# Need spark SQL to merge CDC (Json) files with snapshot parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a workflow that needs to run SQL on final snapshot of a collection from Mongo db. To achieve this we had taken full dump of mongodb into AWS S3 + enabled CDC on the mongodb collection. The CDC outputs the files as JSON onto S3. Now the target is to merge the CDC files into Snapshot (parquet) and generate a new snapshot parquet using minimum resources and smallest time.

**Approach 1**

No optimizations. vcore sec = 20k

To achieve this we have used the below SQL. The resultset of the below query is dumped as parquet file onto s3 (driver memory 1g, executor memory 2g, time 20k vcore sec)

```
with cdcTable as
(
    select *
      from input where cdc_pk in (select max(cdc_pk) from input group by cdc_oid)
),
snapshotTable as
(
    select *
      from snapshot where _id.oid not in (select cdc_oid from input where cdc_oid is not null)
),
resultTable as
(
    select * from snapshotTable
    union all
    select * from cdcTable
)
select * from resultTable
```

**Approach 2**

Optimization done. Vcore sec = 40k

To optimize this we had partitioned the input cdc file by created date derived from mongo objectid.  We had partitioned snapshot table by created table and changed the sql query to the below.

`_created_date` -> is the mongo db row creation date (derived from object id : _id)

```
with _cdc_pks as (
    select max(cdc_pk) as _cdc_pk, _id.oid as _oid , __created_date_ as _created_date
    from input
    group by __created_date_, _id.oid
),
 _cdc as (
    select cdc_pk,
           cdc_oid,
           __created_date_,
           @{getRemainingColumns('[bucket]/schemas/[dbname]-[collection].json' ) }
    from input i1, _cdc_pks i2
    where i1.cdc_pk = i2._cdc_pk and i1.__created_date_ = i2._created_date
),
 _snapshot as (
    select cdc_pk,
           cdc_oid,
           __created_date_,
           @{getRemainingColumns('[bucket]/schemas/[dbname]-[collection].json' ) }
    from snapshot, _cd_pks
    where snapshot.__created_date__ = _cdc_pks_._created_date and snapshot._id.oid not in _cdc_pks._oid
)
select * from _cdc
union all
select * from _snapshot
```

The issue now is that the resource consumption has doubled the time taken has also doubled (-vcore seconds). What surprises me is that : originall every key had to be lookedup across full table, but now every key is being lookedup only in that partition, which means the new sql should take less time --which is not the case.

Any thoughts where I am going wrong? Any pointers?

**Appendix**

Btw, I had tried apache iceberg, and apache hudi (+raised ticket on forums) both ran into never ending issues so coming back to SQL as last resort.

In the above @getAllColumns() is a mvel expression that reads the json file and generates all columns.